# url search for file in subdirectory instead from public_html using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website in which I write code for htaccess but the thing which I wanted to do is not happening. I have url which is:

```
http://www.example.com/demo.php?id=234&title=ask%20me%20a%20question
```

I converted to below url using htaccess:

```
http://www.example.com/234/ask%20me%a%question
```

htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([a-z]+)/$ demo.php?url=$1&url2=$2
```

So. the problem is converted url is search for related file in subdirectory instead of server root i.e; public_html. I want to know how could this problem will solve. 
Plz help me. Thanks.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: @Starkeen i rewrite my question by writing code which i tried.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter in your request requires that characters other than `a-z` be included, but you are limiting it to `a-z`.

In addition, you are requesting `234` in the URI, but checking for 4 numbers in the first parameter.

As such, change your rule to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{3,4})/([^/]+)/?$ demo.php?url=$1&url2=$2 [L]
```

Changes

1. Allow 3 or 4 numbers in the first parameter. If you want to be more flexible, you can change it to `([0-9]+)`.
2. Check for all characters other than `/` in the second parameter.
3. Make the trailing slash optional using `/?`.
4. Add the `L` flag to stop rewriting if the rule is matched (always good to have for when you add other rules).

Comment: thanks for such good info. But still your answer doesn't help me out.